# Systemd keeps restarting a process

Tags: 16.04, systemd, mate, gnome-screensaver

I've installed Mate on top of Unity in Ubuntu 16.04. In my process list, `gnome-screensaver` appears persistently:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
username  8434     1  0 09:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
```

I can kill it successfully, but it will always reappear after the next time the lockscreen is activated (when I close and reopen the laptop).

Its PPID is always 1, which is systemd. grep shows no files within the `/etc/systemd/` directory that contain "gnome" or "screensaver". I can't figure out why it keeps restarting.  How do I stop it?

**Edit:**

```
dpkg -L gnome-screensaver | grep service
```

shows the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.ScreenSaver.service` with contents

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.gnome.ScreenSaver
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
```

This looks like how the process is being restarted.  I guess that somewhere is a file or setting that tells systemd "in response to X signal from dbus, start this service," with X being something related to closing and reopening the laptop.  Is this correct, and is there a way to identify that file or setting?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to *Ask Ubuntu*.

If you don't want gnome-screensaver, you can try to just uninstall it:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-screensaver
```

You can also try masking the service, which is telling `systemd` to act like the service doesn't exist:

```
sudo systemctl mask org.gnome.ScreenSaver.service
```

`/etc/systemd` is used for files that *you* manage. `systemd` related files installed by the `systemd` are often not stored there.

You can find where the `systemd` service file for a package is installed like this:

```
 dpkg -L gnome-screensaver | grep service
```

Comment: I don't want to uninstall it, but I didn't know about masking.  That might work if I can't find the real problem.  The last part is another great tip I didn't know, thanks!  Based on it, I've edited my question with info that the process restart seems related to dbus.  Is there a way to narrow it down more?

Comment: @DarienMarks the real problem? [What is the real problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What do you intend to achieve by killing gnome-screensaver?

Comment: @muru By killing gnome-screensaver, I intended to determine that gnome-screensaver is the source of the lock screen that shouldn't appear when I open my laptop. Turns out it was. Now I want to determine what process makes it keep restarting in order to learn enough about systemd and dbus to solve a whole host of related problems that exist due to interference between Unity and my desktop environments. The XY problem you've linked to concerns users who become fixated on their attempted solution. I have no attempted solution, so I'm not sure how it applies to me.

Comment: @DarienMarks you wanted to determine what's showing the lock screen that shouldn't be appearing (=X). You determine some method to determine that and ask about that (=Y), and when somebody answers that, say that something else is the real problem. Classic XY to me.

Comment: I've never asked this on any forum I've been a part of, but... can I block users here?

Comment: Not I'm aware of, but you can flag answers and comments that you believe violate community guidelines.